# SQL query to extract only the "current" wp_posts?

Tags: sql, posts

The wp_posts table seems to retain all revisions of the same, ok very similar but presumably different, posts/pages/whatever.

I'm somewhat conversant with SQL but not WordPress. I need to extract just those records which would appear on the public facing site; so just the most recent revision, and not all the superceded rows. Not sure how to filter the fields. Obviously something more complicated than:

```
select *
from wp_posts
where post_status in ('publish','revision')
order by post_modified desc
```

which has 'duplicates' and seems to miss some stuff.

Comment: Do you **need** to do this via SQL? Why not WordPress functions?

Comment: +1 on @Rarst. Plus: If you get duplicates, use `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rather than constructing query from scratch, it is easier to see what exactly is WordPress querying when API function is used:

```
get_posts(array(
             'numberposts' => -1,
         ));

var_dump( $wpdb->last_query );
```

Gives following SQL:

```
SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts 
WHERE 1=1 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

Comment: @Elliott yeah, I wish someone had told me about that trick couple years earlier than I learned it :)

Comment: You should always use wpdb to get the current table prefix.

Comment: @Brian Fegter this query is generated by WP and so already has correct prefix in place. This approach will always give query, specific to installation.

Comment: @Rarst - DOH :)

Comment: Awesome! So it's really just looking for a status of "publish".  It must set to something else if the post is updated. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this as Wordpress does heavy lifting here:

```
$args = array(
    'showposts' => 10,
);
$posts = query_posts();
var_dump($posts);
```

You learn more about adding arguments to query_posts http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

You should also use the Wordpress database class when creating manual MYSQL queries. You can learn more here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb  Wordpress also includes a great function for escaping data in queries to keep your operation safe: esc_sql($string);

You can use the Wordpress db class like this:

```
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'");
```

Using $wpdb->before your the table name prepends the assigned database prefix. This is important because you can have multiple Wordpress installations in one database using table prefixes. $wpdb-> will grab the correct prefix context.